# AngularJs DatePicker and Ajax - which format to store in MySql database?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, timestamp

I want to create a new object, with a start & end date using the standard UI-bootstrap DatePicker.

I will send these date, using Ajax, to my server, where some PHP which I code will store it in a MySql database.

Coming from a PHP background, my first instinct is to store date/time as a Unix timestamp.

Since (Angular) JS has a millisecond resolution and Unix timestamps have a second resolution, that involves multiplying/dividing by 1000.

My server is returning data as a JSON, and I would rather not change that.

Ideally, I would like to do any conversion on  the server, since it ought to have more processing power, and just initialze by AngularJS model fronm the JSON received.

Would it be acceptable to store the date as strings in the MySql database, rather than a timestamp? That way the downloaded data could be used unchanged to initialize the DatePicker.

Since I am having trouble getting the DatePicker to show the date which it receives from the server (as Unix timestamp), this seems like the simpler approach, but is there anything to watch out for, if I do so?

How do others do this?

Comment: I'm custom to this situation and I've always stored the data in a DATETIME column as '2016-03-31 14:23:33' and then format it either in the query or in php.

Comment: You definitely don't want to store them as strings because they're not.

Comment: Then how & where do you do the manipulation? How/where do you multiple/divide by 1000?

Comment: I don't.  You might want to look into moment.js though.

Comment: You don't? Then you are not using JS timestamps, which are 1000 times Unix timestamps. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but no, I do not use JS timestamps.

Comment: NP. As I said, I use the Angular UI-bootsrap which uses JS timestamps. To store those as MySql DATETIME requires conversion.

Comment: I guess I've used the javascript date function like this: 
var json_from_server = {"date":"2016-03-31 13:46:23"};
var json_from_server.date = new Date(json_from_server.date);

Comment: So, since tou say that you don't store it in MySQl as a string, but as a DATETIME, I imagne that you are converting from DATETIME to "2016-03-31 13:46:23"} on the server ?

Comment: I created a Fiddle demonstrating how I do this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwot3exe/

Comment: I really **do** appreciate you taking the time to code that. However, running it does nothing, I cannot see the structure ofyour MySQl table , nor how you sire the data(nor an Angulr DatePicker), so that doesn't help me.

Comment: The date_time column is a DATETIME type as I mentioned before. I simply wanted to demonstrate how I take DATETIME data from a MySQL table and apply it to a JavaScript object for the DatePicker to handle.  I would hope you are able to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Are you **sure** that you have working code that uses this? Because a JS timesampt is equal to a DATEPICKER * 1000 - I do nto see any conversion taking place.

Comment: Um, yes, I am sure.  It's used heavily on a daily basis without a hitch.  And, per Angular UI Bootstrap docs: ng-model $  - The date object. Needs to be a Javascript Date object.

Comment: Yes, I do undertysand that, but a MySql object is **not** a JS date object. Mysql has resoultion of 1 second and JS has resolution of 1ms - a factor of 1,000 difference. I fail to see how this can work without conversion. One of us obviosly misundesrtands the other. I  am willing to believe ttta it is me. But do you undesratnd the point that I cam tring to make?

Comment: I am sorry, but it is bedtime over here. I will have to continue this coneversation tomorow. Thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: "but a MySql object is not a JS date object"

Yes, I know this.  Thats why I convert it to a JS date object in the Javascript.  It's very obvious in the fiddle link I sent you.